# Using selenium - I am not able to login to https://passport.amazon.work

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium - I am not able to login to https://passport.amazon.work. Here is my code:

```
package selenium;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class AWSJobs 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium-java-3.141.59\\chromedriver.exe");
        //Create Driver object for Chrome browser
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //Let's login to Starbucks.com
        driver.get("https://passport.amazon.work");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signInFormUsernameInputField")).sendKeys("myEMailId@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signInFormPasswordInputField")).sendKeys("MyPassword");
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-main btn btn-default btn-block")).submit();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.jobs/en/locations/dallasfort-worth-area-tx");
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("job-tile"));
        java.util.Iterator<WebElement> i = elements.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) 
        {
            WebElement element = i.next();
            if (element.isDisplayed()) {
              System.out.println();
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

I tried this [url](https://account.amazon.jobs/candidate/dashboard/profile)  with only userId but no success.

**Edit1**
As suggested tried this

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-main btn btn-default btn-block")).submit();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-group sign-in-margin']//button")).submit();
```

But still getting error.

Answer (score 2):

You code wrong in this line:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-main btn btn-default btn-block")).submit();
```

Try to change to be:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-group sign-in-margin']//button")).submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But even after that change, getting issues...updating the question as comments doesn't allow me to write so much

Comment: @Ashu I'm sure, with your origin code, you can't click `login button`, and now that's issue has solved. Now you're facing with different issue after success login. Sadly I can't help more because I'm haven't account to do it. The important question is : `What you're getting the error now?` and `Can you provide the html after the login?`